# How do I tell if my laptop's camera is really supported on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, camera

I have a new T14 and it has a dual camera setup with both color and b&w cameras. While I can see a video stream when using zoom and the like, I'm not sure whether that stream uses the b&w camera (for better lighting). How can I tell? `lshw` shows the vendor of the camera is 'Generic' and `driver=uvcvideo`

Comment: If you can use the cameras in zoom, they are apparently supported. The cameras are supported bij the generic driver, which means that special features of the camera, if any, may not be supported. It is a bit unclear what other support you need.

Comment: "I'm not sure whether that stream uses the b&w camera"